# How to exclude numbers in a series and still plot the graph?

Tags: plotting, summation

I want to plot this: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-{10}\atop n\ne \pm 1}^{10} \dfrac {4i(-1)^{n}n}{(n^2 - 1)^2}e^{inx}$

but have no idea how I can exclude the cases for when $ n = \pm 1 $. I don't wish to split up the summation into two parts either.

Thanks.

Comment: Look up the documentation for `Sum`, especially the 4th form.

Answer (score 4):

I actually couldn't find a question on exclusion of summation indices. Let me know if I missed it.

```
f[x_] = 
Sum[(4 I (-1)^n n)/(1 - n^2)^2 Exp[I n x], {n, Complement[Range[-10, 10], {-1, 1}]}] //  
FullSimplify;
```

or even [**more proper**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1290/13)

```
f[x_] = Sum[(4 I (-1)^n n)/(1 - n^2)^2 Exp[I n x], 
        {n, DeleteCases[Range[-10, 10], Alternatives @@ {-1, 1}]}] // FullSimplify;

f[x] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -15, 15}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the simplest approach

```
Sum[If[n == -1 || n == 1, 0, (4 I (-1)^n n)/(1 - n^2)^2 Exp[I n x]], {n, -10, 10}]
```